# Get ID for Postgres Server Installation

Tags: postgresql

We want to create a license system where multiple users connected to a Postgres server share the same key.

This means the license key must somehow contain the information which server it was created for, so the key won't work on a second server plus clients.

So I'm searching for an ID that is as unique as possible. So far without much luck.

```
SELECT version();
```

Returns a string like the following:

```
PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54), 64-bit
```

Which is probably a little different for each Postgres installation, but that's not good enough (especially since we want to bundle Postgres with our application).

Is there any information I can access that is a bit more varied, like maybe installation time etc.?

Comment: What about the output of [pg_controldata](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgcontroldata.html)? I _think_ the "Database system identifier" is pretty unique

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wouldn't that mean that you lose your license after a major database upgrade?

Comment: Note that `pg_controldata` is a shell command; PostgreSQL does not AFAIK expose the sysid or other control/checkpoint data the SQL level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, as a_horse_with_no_name notes, use the database system identifier. However:

- The sysid does not change when you clone a database via `pg_basebackup`, SAN snapshots, etc. The Timeline ID *may* increment, but doesn't always, depending on method used for copying.
- The sysid *does* change if you dump and reload a database to a new instance, even though the database contents are the same.
- Many PostgreSQL read/write master instances may have the same sysid if they're all cloned from a common pre-configured postgres in some container template or similar.
- It's trivial to regenerate the sysid, or set it to whatever you want it to be.
- The sysid is not preserved by `pg_upgrade`

so personally, I do not recommend using the sysid. If I had to do disaster recovery and restore a dump into a newly `initdb`'d database and your software locked me out, I'd be finding a new vendor and a lawyer.

It doesn't help that it's not currently accessible via SQL, only by using `pg_controldata`.

Definitely do *not* use the version string. It'll be the same for any set of deployments from the same set of packages, distributed binaries, or whatever.

There isn't really anything like what you want in PostgreSQL, and I'm not sure there *can* be because of the things that people routinely do. Cloning DBs, snapshots and restores, copying a DB for a QA/staging instance, etc, etc.

---

My personal advice: don't do this. I've had to break systems like this in business emergencies when the license system threatens business continuity. (It's rarely hard). I strongly advocate against tools with active license enforcement when I'm involved in purchasing. Dongles are even worse. Pay attention to the fact that *even Microsoft* uses "soft" license enforcement, where it helps you track compliance and warns you, but doesn't try to break the system if it thinks you're not in compliance. This is what the legal system is for.

Oh, if you *really* feel you must do this, Microsoft Windows systems have a SID. But your customers will hate you if they have to reinstall the OS.

Similarly, there's the hardware TPM. But they'll hate you even more if they restore an OS backup image to new hardware and the DB refuses to start.